# Explanation for 'uninitialized value' warning

Tags: perl

Why `perl -we '$c = $c+3'` rises

```
Use of uninitialized value $c in addition (+) at -e line 1.
```

and `perl -we '$c += 3'` doesn't complain about uninitialized value?

**UPDATE**

Does documentation or some book like 'Perl best practices' mention such behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `perldoc perlop` has a little explanation:

```
Assignment Operators
       "=" is the ordinary assignment operator.

       Assignment operators work as in C.  That is,

           $a += 2;

       is equivalent to

           $a = $a + 2;

       although without duplicating any side effects that dereferencing the
       lvalue might trigger, such as from tie()
```

With `B::Concise` helper, we can see the trick:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e '$c += 3'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <#> gvsv[*c] s
4  <$> const[IV 3] s
5  <2> add[t2] vKS/2
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e '$c = $c + 3'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <#> gvsv[*c] s
4  <$> const[IV 3] s
5  <2> add[t3] sK/2
6  <#> gvsv[*c] s
7  <2> sassign vKS/2
8  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

**Update**

After searching in `perldoc`, I saw that this problem had been documented in `perlsyn`:

```
Declarations
       The only things you need to declare in Perl are report formats and subroutines (and sometimes not even subroutines).  A variable
       holds the undefined value ("undef") until it has been assigned a defined value, which is anything other than "undef".  When used as a
       number, "undef" is treated as 0; when used as a string, it is treated as the empty string, ""; and when used as a reference that
       isn't being assigned to, it is treated as an error.  If you enable warnings, you'll be notified of an uninitialized value whenever
       you treat "undef" as a string or a number.  Well, usually.  Boolean contexts, such as:

           my $a;
           if ($a) {}

       are exempt from warnings (because they care about truth rather than definedness).  Operators such as "++", "--", "+=", "-=", and
       ".=", that operate on undefined left values such as:

           my $a;
           $a++;

       are also always exempt from such warnings.
```

Comment: `without duplicating any side effects that dereferencing the
lvalue might trigger` is written with an admirable neglect for human understanding, if it includes what this question is about, which, for all I know, it might very well do.

Comment: @TLP, hum? "[side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29)" and "[lvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29#lrvalue)" are rather basic computer science terms.  `sub f :lvalue { print "!\n"; $x }  f() = f() + 1; print "--\n"; f() += 1;`

Comment: I don't see how this answer has anything to do with the OP's question. It doesn't have anything to do with warnings at all! Or are you incorrectly claiming that "without duplicating any side effects that dereferencing the lvalue might trigger" means it won't issue warnings? That's completely wrong (and can easily be disproven by initializing `$c` to `abc`).

Comment: @ikegami: Yeah, I think the output of `B::Concise` can help for this problem, but we must digg deeper into `perl` source.

Comment: If you think that, then by all means explain how. So far, you've only shown that different operators produce different code, which goes without saying.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm doing some research with `perl` source. I also find a documentation with this problem in `perlsyn`, see my update answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54065/discussion-between-gnouc-and-ikegami).

Comment: @ikegami I am saying that it is almost illegible. It says 'duplicating side effects', for gods sake. Do you need a comp sci degree to understand that statement? I seriously don't know.

Comment: @TLP, Then look it up. I even provided a link. "In computer science, a function or expression is said to have a side effect if, in addition to returning a value, it also modifies some state or has an observable interaction with calling functions or the outside world." Do you have an alternate word for that??? This is introductory programming terminology, such as "function". In fact, it's a concept you must understand to define "function", as it's what differentiates functions from procedures.

Comment: @ikegami I see, so in computer science, "side effect" has a narrower definition than the rest of the world? I did not know that. So, where does the "dereferencing" come in to play? As far as I know, dereferencing a variable in perl would be something like `@$foo`.

Comment: @TLP, Not really different if you start with the premise that the function of a function is to return a value based on its arguments (as per mathematics). // "Accessing" might be a better word then "dereferencing".

Answer (score 4):

Because it makes sense for addition to warn when adding things other than numbers, but it's very convenient for `+=` not to warn for undefined values.

As Gnouc found, this is documented in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html):

> Operators such as ++ , -- , += , -= , and .= , that operate on undefined variables such as:
>
> ```
> undef $a;
> $a++;
> ```
>
> are also always exempt from such warnings.

Comment: It certainly is convenient, but is such behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: I guess `-MO=Concise` is not helpful here?

Comment: No. Even if `-MO=Concise` did list what warnings were enabled for each instruction, it would say the same in both cases.